# why isnt the container centering?

Tags: css

Why is the container with the background colour f0f0f0 not centering for me? I gave the parent element the css style of text-align: center but it seems to ignre it?

http://codepen.io/ELiHimself/pen/qOXVYJ

```
<body>

  <header></header>

  <section class="container">
      <div class="box" id="box1">box1</div>
      <div class="box" id="box2">box2</div>
      <div class="box" id="box3">box3</div>  
  </section>


</body>
```

sass

```
*
  margin: 0

body
  text-align: center

.container
  max-width: 1170px
  padding-top: 100px
  background-color: #f0f0f0

header
  height: 100px
  background-color: red

.box
  padding: 100px
  border: 1px solid black
  display: inline-block
```

Comment: Your css appears to be missing end line ; and containing { } characters.

Comment: thats why i said "sass" on top. Its not css its sass

Comment: Ah - I saw your css tag and thought you were using css and sass was a typo.  Carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`section`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) is a `block` level element. Apply:

```
.container {
    ...
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to your `container` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: /* your width */
}
```

This should to the trick

Comment: Hi! If you found my answer useful, please upvote it!